# Entry source criteria not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, entry-criteria

I have the following criteria on my entry source in a journey:

CRITERIA
CampaignMember:ContactId WASSET AND CampaignMember:Status CONTAINS Responded OR CampaignMember:Status CONTAINS Received

The entry source fires on the update of the CampaignMember object.

CampaignMember:Status can be Sent, Respondend or Received.

When such status is changed from Sent to either Responded or Received, the logic works and everything goes well. 
But if the status gets changed from Responded to received or viceversa, it doesn't work. If I firstly change a Responded/Received status to Sent, then change it back to one of the two, it works fine.

So basically, it only works when the status gets changed from Sent to either Received/Responded.

I've tried with both CONTAINS and EQUALS, but nothing changes. Also tried with CampaignMember:Status does not equal to Sent, but same thing happens.

Any idea of why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Flows/process builder to kick off and make the api calls to inject a subscriber into a journey the subscriber has to go from not meeting criteria to meet criteria. When that status is either received or responded they meet criteria and since they change to recieved or responded they still meet criteria. You would need a process to either set them to a value where they don't meet criteria then meet criteria. Or use another field called 'Updated' which you can then set if they made an update and use that to inject if equal true, and then also use the journey to set that field back to false, with an update activity